# Python built in list function doesn't work in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I don't know if anyone experienced the same issue as I do with Google Colab. This simple line of code doesn't work:

```
list(range(10)
```

On a jupyter notebook, I got my list [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], but on colab, I got an error (see screenshot attached). Any idea why this is happening and what can be done to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unXgU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMAhS.png)

Comment: That's because in the second image, you seem to have created an object named list somewhere. Never name objects the same as built in types, it just causes problems.

Comment: You probably wrote `list = ...` somewhere earlier, shadowing the list constructor with a non-callable object.

Comment: As the error message says, the name ``list`` points to a ``list`` *instance* in your second case. You did something akin to ``list = [1, 2, 3, 4]`` earlier.

Comment: Hello everyone, yes you are actually right. This is a notebook I have used to make many tests and indeed I have created an object named list a while ago. Stupid me. Thanks a lot for your very quick support. Have a great day guys.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to find a solution to your problem. Please refrain from posting pictures of code--rather, post them as code blocks within your original question. Cheers.